# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to build this dockerfile and then run it but I'm getting this error `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./deployment-service": permission denied: unknown.`

This is my docker file, I've created the volumes and networks

```
FROM golang:1.19.2-alpine as builder

RUN apk add bash

RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client ansible git

RUN mkdir /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN go build -o deployment-service cmd/deployment-service/main.go

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/

COPY --from=builder /workspace .

ARG DEFAULT_PORT=8080
ENV PORT $DEFAULT_PORT

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["./deployment-service"]
```

this is my run command,

```
docker run --name=${CONTAINER_NAME} -d --rm -p ${PORT}:80 -e DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URI=mongodb://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME}:27017/ -e DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_SERVER_SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY} -e ANSIBLE_CONFIG='./jam-ansible/ansible.cfg' -e DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_ANSIBLE_SUBMISSION_ROOT=${DEPLOYMENT_ROOT} -v ${DEPLOYMENT_VOLUME}:${DEPLOYMENT_ROOT} --network=${NETWORK_NAME} server:latest
```

help to get my issue solved.

Comment: Does the same `go build ...; ./deployment-service` sequence work without Docker?  Does specifying a package name and not just a single file name work better, `go build ... ./cmd/deployment-service`?

Comment: yeah, it's working. I mistakenly deleted the the binary from the container once after that I started facing this issue.

Comment: ...in the `docker run` command, you have a `-v` option hiding a `$DEPLOYMENT_ROOT` directory in the container.  If that's the image's `/root` directory, it will definitely cause this problem; delete that option to use the binary built into the image.  (`docker build`ing an updated image shouldn't be much more expensive than `go build`ing a binary; you do not need a volume mount to inject code.)

Comment: No that's not the image's root directory, it's some data in the container that I want to keep. Also, I solved the error message when I changed this name of binary to something else. As I said earlier the issue started after I deleted the binary inside the container, but in my knowledge if a container is removed everything related to it is removed, so if I make a new container after removing the container(from which I deleted the binary) it should generate the binary again and should work fine, but it's not happening.

Comment: A REALLY dumb way for this to happen is that you are specifying the docker run options in the wrong order.  This will show the error: 'docker run <container-name> -p 8000:8000' ... but this will work 'docker run -p 8000:8000 <container-name>'    I wasted 30 minutes on this stupidness.   Docker 'run' really wants the image name as the last parameter, regardless of the convention for optional parameters (at least on Windows where I hit this issue and google lead me here!).

Comment: Thanks @PeterWalkley! I wasted to much time on that one too...

Answer (score 10):

It seems lack of permission to execute **deployment-service**. You can add

```
RUN chmod +x deployment-service
```

before `CMD ["./deployment-service"]`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need to edit the permissions of the deployment-service file.

try running

```
chmod a+x ./deployment-service
```

in the terminal then trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may end up getting this error because you have not specified an entrypoint for your container.
You can do that using `ENTRYPOINT` inside the `Dockerfile`

Below is a .NET example:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "application.dll"]
```

Comment: Just adding an entrypoint "/bin/bash" solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the below error while trying to run the container using the **command**:

```
docker container run -p portnumber:portnumber amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
```

**ERROR**:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

- I used `amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk` docker image and in `dockerfile` instead of `bash`, I changed it to `sh` and it worked as `bash` didn't work with `alpine`.

Command changed from:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "java -jar test.jar"]
```

to:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar test.jar"]
```

Answer (score -5):

Run ***docker system prune  -a***
clear all cache and stopped containers
and then try starting the docker.
It'll start.

Comment: This is excessive.  You are removing all networks, volumes etc.