# Can't build any golang docker images successfully, permission denied

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have been trying to build a golang docker image for my application, but I can't get any of the images to build:

I have tried theese two Dockerfiles:

```
FROM golang:1.20

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN go build -o ./app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "./app" ]
```

and

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine as builder

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o out

FROM alpine:latest

# Copy the compiled binary from the builder image
COPY --from=builder /app/out ./out

# Start the program
CMD ["./out"]
```

The Error (different binary name, but the same error):

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./out": permission denied: unknown
```

I have tried setting the exec bit on the outputted files, but it still won't work. **I have been able to use the exact same dockerfiles before, but now they seem to not want to work.**

Any help is appreciated, thanks

I have tried chowning the build binary, but it didnt work.
I have tried different dockerifles, but it didnt work.

Worked fine 3 days ago, doesn't want to work now.
Also tried docker system prune --all, no luck
I have looked for other SO answers, nothing worked.

Comment: I recently faced this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078744/docker-error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-create-shim-task-oci-runtime-crea

I accidentally deleted the binary file inside the container and I started facing this issue. Try using a different name for the binary, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by me building the root folder of the project inside the container, not the /cmd folder, where the main file was located. Make sure to chmod +x the outputted file in the container, and make sure to build the correct files.

/facepalm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's pretty clear. I was building in /, which only contains lib files. I needed to build in /cmd/, which contains the main files.

Answer (score 1):

I used the provided examples to write two different ways of building Docker images.

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
COPY ./go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o server
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/server"]
```

AND

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
COPY ./go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o server

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/server /opt/app/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/opt/app/server"]
```

You can also check out my [github](https://github.com/ares0x/practice/tree/main/deploy/webserver-stackoverflow).